# Get value onblur from input fields in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, onblur

Below is how I made an alert showing the "dynamic" id using onblur.  I have a while loop with input fields so the id is pulling from a unique id in a database.

How would I get the value too?  Normally I would just set a variable like usual but it's in a loop so I'm not understanding how.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doUpdateEntries(clicked_id) {
        alert(clicked_id);
        // how do I get the value AND id?
    }
</script>

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    <input onblur="doUpdateEntries(this.id);" id=".$row['entry_id']." name=".$row['entry_id']." type="text" value=".$row['reviews'].">
}
```

Comment: instead of doUpdateEntries(this.id) you can use doUpdateEntries(this), clicked_id.value will give you its value and clicked_id.id will give you its id.

Comment: hey that's perfect!  I would love to give you credit for the answer.  For now i'll just upvote your comment.

Comment: `onblur="doUpdateEntries(this.id, this.value);"`? Or even better just pass the whole event target to the function.

Comment: @LITguy I feel this does not fit as an answer, I am glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply pass through the value to the function `doUpdateEntries` as another parameter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doUpdateEntries(id, value) {
        alert(id);
        alert(value);
    }
</script>

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    <input onblur="doUpdateEntries(this.id, this.value);" id=".$row['entry_id']." name=".$row['entry_id']." type="text" value=".$row['reviews'].">
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ankit mentions… just pass in `this`, à la

```
<input onblur="doUpdateEntries(this);" id=".$row['entry_id']." name=".$row['entry_id']." type="text" value=".$row['reviews'].">
```

Below is how I made an alert showing the "dynamic" id using `onblur`. I have a `while` loop with input fields so the `id` is pulling from a unique id in a database.

How would I get the value too? Normally I would just set a variable like usual but it's in a loop so I'm not understanding how.

```
function doUpdateEntries(_this) {
    var _id = _this.id;
    var _name = _this.value;
}
```